# Autoloader unit test - first attempt

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am learning TDD and I want to test my AutoLoader class, what needs to do the next job:

- do a check is the namespace is string
- do a check, is the path to directory parameter is a string
- do a check is the path to directory what I want to load is exists, directory and readable.

There will be more jobs, but I am newbee, so I need your opinion about my test:

```
<?php

namespace Myframework\Application\Autoloader;

class Autoloader {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path;

    public function __construct($namespace, $pathToClassesDirectory = '') {
        if (!is_string($namespace)) {
            throw new \Exception('Namespace must be string');
        }
        if (!is_string($pathToClassesDirectory)) {
            throw new \Exception('Path to directory parameter should be string');
        }
        if (!file_exists($pathToClassesDirectory) || !is_dir($pathToClassesDirectory) || !is_readable($pathToClassesDirectory)) {
            throw new \Exception('Path to directory is not accessible to read: "' . $pathToClassesDirectory . '"');
        }
        $this->namespace = $namespace;
        $this->path = $pathToClassesDirectory;
    }

}
```

The class:

```
    <?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/**
 * @author vaso
 */
require_once '../system/Application/Autoloader/Autoloader.php';

class AutoloaderTest extends TestCase {

    protected $Autoloader;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->Autoloader = new Myframework\Application\Autoloader\Autoloader(TEST_NAMESPACE, BASE_PATH);
    }

    public function tearDown() {
        unset($this->Autoloader);
    }

    public function testConstructorCall() {
        new Myframework\Application\Autoloader\Autoloader('nameSpaceAsString', BASE_PATH);
    }

    public function testConstructorCallNameSpaceIsNotStringException() {
        $this->expectException('Exception');
        new Myframework\Application\Autoloader\Autoloader(2);
    }

    public function testConstructorCallPathIsNotStringException() {
        $this->expectException('Exception');
        $notStringForPath = new stdClass();
        new Myframework\Application\Autoloader\Autoloader(TEST_NAMESPACE, $notStringForPath);
    }

    public function testIsDirectoryExistsException() {
        $this->expectException('Exception');
        new Myframework\Application\Autoloader\Autoloader('x', 'Failed directory what not exist');
    }

}
```

Test passed, and my methods are works, I am happy. But I doubt this is not how TDD works even if I follow every requirements.

My questions are:

- Is it ok to use constants in test what comes from `bootstrap.php` to define path?
- All of the test ok, but is this the right way to test a constructor? I feel no for some reason, if its ok, please tell me, if not, please tell me why.

I found a lot of resources about TDD, videos, books, but testing the constructor is not in it.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  Where does loading actually happen?  Also, I would think that in this day and age, if one were to build an autoloader, they would do son in PSR-4 compliant fashion.  See PSR-4 examples implementations here: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md  I guess I don't understand the need to "roll your own" autoloader at this point when this is territory that is very well covered in PHP.

Comment: Load is not implemented yet, and I am loading as PSR suggested in other projects. That is a unit, what I can test by unit test. Yes, I am know unit test is for units, but if I want to be sure that my code is coveraged I should write tests for the constructor too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've got these answers:

Testing constructor is totally unnecessary if you follow this: [Constructor does Real Work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/). Unit test for units. The constructor only job is to build the object, nothing else, no new objects creation, no initializing, etc...

For constants: I see no reason why do not use constants (for example for a path) to help me to access my classes for tests.